# Interfacing with a S6B0741

Tags: communication, lcd, programming, interface, glcd

I am using a LPC4300 board to interface with a graphical LCD, a S6B0741. I have been trying to get it initialized, but I am not sure if I am sending the commands the correct way.

The code I have right now:

```
  GPIO_ClearValue (LCD_PINS.GPIOPortNum, (1<<LCD_PINS.GPIOBits[10]));
  GPIO_ClearValue (LCD_PINS.GPIOPortNum, (1<<LCD_PINS.GPIOBits[9]));
  GPIO_SetValue (LCD_PINS.GPIOPortNum, (1<<LCD_PINS.GPIOBits[12]));
  GPIO_SetValue (LCD_PINS.GPIOPortNum, (1<<LCD_PINS.GPIOBits[8]));

  SetBits (data); // sets the I/O data bus

  GPIO_ClearValue (LCD_PINS.GPIOPortNum, (1<<LCD_PINS.GPIOBits[8]));
  GPIO_ClearValue (LCD_PINS.GPIOPortNum, (1<<LCD_PINS.GPIOBits[12]));
```

All ports are defined as input ports.

I have tried following the initialization routine, as described in the datasheet, but it hasn't been working.

Is this correct?

*EDIT* 
Should have had this in the original post, since the code as it is doesn't make sense really.

The pins are:

- 0-7 data bus
- 8 E
- 9 RW
- 10 RS
- 11 RESETB
- 12 CSB

The board is configured to use the 6800 Parallel Interface Mode.

EIDT2: Erroneously put it as 8080 mode rather than 6800.

Comment: I would expect /Wr to be initialised high, then after setting bits I would expect to see /Wr being pulled low then high. No need to do anything with Rd - are you sure it is Rd and not /Rd though?

Comment: also why not improve your code by creating named constants for your lines. eg. #define RD  (1<<LCD_PINS.GPIOBits[8])

Comment: I was doing it that way due to the fact that the pins are declared in a different file from the LCD functions, but I see now that's kinda pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not correct.

You should initialise the control lines to an inactive state at the start (CSB and E high), then to write data do the following:

```
Set your data bus lines to be outputs from the microprocessor
enable the display: /CSB low
set the RW line low
Write the command or data to the data bus lines
set the RS line as required
set the E line low
reset the E line to high
disable the display /CSB high
```

if you are making multiple writes, or you only have the one display on the bus  you can leave the display enabled (/CSB low) while you change the data and then pulse the E line again.

You only need to set RW high if you need to read data from the display - don't forget to change the data bus lines on your MCU to be inputs before doing this.

Comment: Used the above, the LCD is still not working but hopefully it's not due to the commands anymore.

Comment: Are your CS and Reset lines active high or low? other than that, you typically need a specific sequence of commands to initialise the display. Some commands also need pauses after /Wr, while they are processed. Use a scope to check that the signals are in the correct sequence and that the commands are being presented on the data bus correctly. - Also make sure contrast is turned up enough on display :-)

Comment: Reset is set to high. I don't have a CS line... or you mean CSB? Yes, I was going to check if the display is receiving the right signals and such.

Comment: sorry yes I meant CSB - just checked data sheet it is active low - so set it low as I gave in my answer, before writing.

Comment: Yeah, CSB is low while doing the write then high afterwards.

Comment: Have updated the sequence to match your changed control interface.